# Analyzing Survey Data with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've got some simple survey data that I'd love to have a hand with. I work with PHP/MYSQL.

Basically, the survey has 20 questions with 3 possible answers for each: Y, N and N/A. I want to 'score' each survey at the end using the formula:  Y/(Y+N).

**The Question:** How do I actually come up with the 'SCORE' column at the end?  Using a SQL query or using PHP (somehow)?  Is there some kind of `COUNTIF` function in MYSQL like Excel has?

A query like:  COUNTIF("Y", Column1:Column20) would be awesome—if it existed!

Suggestions appreciated!
(I guess I'm looking for as much procedural advice as technical with this question).

Thanks

Terry

```
            Q1   Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  SCORE
            ---------------------            
Person1 -   y    n   y    n   n/a  50%
Person2 -   y    y   y    y   y    100% 
Person3 -   y    y   y    y   n/a  100%
```

Comment: You have 20 columns, one for each question?

Comment: Other way around—each survey (each person interviewed) answers 20 questions. Each question has just 3 possible answers: Y/N/NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tricks. A long winded SUM(CASE ...)

It'd be easier with one row per question... especially when you add more questions. See [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

```
SELECT
   SUM(
     CASE WHEN Q1 = 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
     CASE WHEN Q2 = 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
     ...
     CASE WHEN Q20 = 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
     )
   /
   SUM(
     CASE WHEN Q1 IN ('y', 'n') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
     CASE WHEN Q2 IN ('y', 'n') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
     ...
     CASE WHEN Q20 IN ('y', 'n') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
     ),
   Person
FROM
   myTable
GROUP BY
   Person
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for this. I'm not sure how I'd achieve the 'one row per question part'. The `Person` field is actually meaningful as well. Each person was assigned an ID and I'm using that too. IE: Person0001, Person 0002, Person 0003. Etc.

Comment: Worked first shot. AWESOME. Thank you.